# finding the longest common difference subsequence

Tags: algorithm

for two given sequences say A and B how can one find the length of the longest common difference  subsequence in them such that the difference between the adjacent elements in these sequences is same. E.g if

> A = {2,4,6,12}

and

> B = {4,8,14}

, then the longest common difference between A and B is {2,6,12} and {4,8,14} as the difference in adjacent temrs in both is same i.e.

> {4,6}

so the length is 3. 
Can longest common subsequence be applied here? or what can be the approach to this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your problem, by substracting each element in each list by the smallest element of the list.

**For example:**

> in A you get :  min(A) = 2 then A = {0,2,4,10}
>
> in B you get : min(B)=4 then B={0,4,10}

and your problem is now to find the **longest common subsequence.**

I guess you can find what you need to solve this problem on SO or anywhere on the web :

[Wikipedia article on longest subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Hope it helps

---

**EDIT**

@Saeed Amiri is right and my answer is true if and only if the smallest element of A and B are in the longest subsequence.

So it gave me a new idea to solve this problem :

Let D(i,j) be the length of the longest subsequence such that its smallest element in A is the ith element of A (sorted) and its smallest element in B is the jth element of B.

then

> D(i,j) = | { A-A(i) } intersect {B - B(j) } |

(notation : |A|=card(A))

you need to find the max of D(i,j) over i and j and you know

> 0<=D(i,j)<=min(|A|-i,|B|-j)

so if you find D(i,j) = min(|A|-i,|B|-j) you don't need to test for i',j' such that  min(|A|-i',|B|-j')<= min(|A|-i,|B|-j)

it's not very efficient (in worst case it's O(n*m)) but at least it corrects my mistake.

it should work,

hope it helps

Comment: no removing smallest element doesn't cause to this: A={0,10,12,20}, B={0,20,22,30} longest common difference will be {2,8} and the length is 3.

Answer (score 1):

If push comes to shove, you can always try adding k to all the elements in one of the sequences and then running longest common subsequence, for all plausible values of k.

If you count how often each possible value occurs in each sequence then you can place an upper bound on the longest common subsequence associated with each k, by working out the number of matches if all equal characters line up. This would allow you to start with the most promising values of k, and then discard values of k that could not possible beat the best answer so far, without actually computing a longest common subsequence for them.